# What does 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'' mean in this code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-requests-html

I am building a quite simple beautifulsoup/requests web scraper, but when running it on a jobs website, the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

appears.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q&l=Norwich%2C%20Norfolk&vjk=139a4549fe3cc48b"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")

job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="resultContent")

python_jobs = results.find_all("h2", string="Python")

for job_element in job_elements:
    title_element = job_element.find("h2", class_="jobTitle")
    company_element = job_element.find("span", class_="companyName")
    location_element = job_element.find("div", class_="companyLocation")
    print(title_element)
    print(company_element)
    print(location_element)
    print()
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: It means that `results` is `None`.

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried this and there was no error this time, but nothing was printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your selector for `results` attribute `id` should be `resultsBody`. The wrong selector causes the error in lines that uses `results`, cause `None` do not has attributes:

```
results = soup.find(id="resultsBody")
```

and also `job_elements` it is an td not a div:

```
job_elements = results.find_all("td", class_="resultContent")
```

You could also chain the selectors with `css selectors`:

```
job_elements = soup.select('#resultsBody td.resultContent')
```

Getting only these that contains `Python`:

```
job_elements = soup.select('#resultsBody td.resultContent:has(h2:-soup-contains("Python"))')
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q&l=Norwich%2C%20Norfolk&vjk=139a4549fe3cc48b"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="resultsBody")

job_elements = results.find_all("td", class_="resultContent")

python_jobs = results.find_all("h2", string="Python")

for job_element in job_elements:
    title_element = job_element.find("h2", class_="jobTitle")
    company_element = job_element.find("span", class_="companyName")
    location_element = job_element.find("div", class_="companyLocation")
    print(title_element)
    print(company_element)
    print(location_element)
    print()
```